# Git LFS upload fails at 0%

Tags: git, git-lfs

There are plethora of questions regarding the failing of git LFS upload, however I have not been able to find an appropriate solution.
My git LFS gets stuck at 0%. I had added a single png image for this commit but I have also already initialized gitlfs and have also added the png extension to the gitattributes.
I am still getting this error response.

```
$ git push origin feature/xyz
Uploading LFS objects:   0% (0/1), 0 B | 1.6 KB/s, done
Fatal error: Server error: https://gitlab.xyz.git/
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.xyz.git/'
```

Answer (score 2):

The message "Server error" means that the remote server returned an HTTP 500 Internal Server Error response.  This means that the server encountered some sort of internal problem and failed to handle the request.

You can retry, but if that doesn't work, then you need to contact the party responsible for maintaining the server and ask them to look into it.  The server probably has logs that can be used to determine what the problem is.  However, there's nothing you can do, since this is a server error, not a client error.